# How to avoid "Length", "Class", "Mode" in a r table that has characters and integers, using summary()?

Tags: r

I am brand spanking new to R.

I am getting the following output for `summary(scores_df)`.

```
   Count           Score         Section        
 Min.   :10.00   Min.   :200.0   Length:38         
 1st Qu.:10.00   1st Qu.:300.0   Class :character  
 Median :10.00   Median :322.5   Mode  :character  
 Mean   :14.47   Mean   :317.5                     
 3rd Qu.:20.00   3rd Qu.:357.5                     
 Max.   :30.00   Max.   :395.0
```

The output I need is

```
 Count           Score          Section  
 Min.   :10.00   Min.   :200.0   Regular:19  
 1st Qu.:10.00   1st Qu.:300.0   Sports :19  
 Median :10.00   Median :322.5               
 Mean   :14.47   Mean   :317.5               
 3rd Qu.:20.00   3rd Qu.:357.5               
 Max.   :30.00   Max.   :395.0
```

**How do I avoid "Length, Class and Mode" in a table that has both Integer and Character class, ONLY using `summary()`?**

Comment: Turn your Section column into a factor rather than a character value. Note that version of R prior to 4.0 used to do this automatically when importing data. If you are following a guide or something it is likely out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to do this would be to change the columns to factors from characters.

Take this example :

```
df <- data.frame(a = c('a', 'b', 'c'), b = 1:3)
summary(df)

#     a                   b      
# Length:3           Min.   :1.0  
# Class :character   1st Qu.:1.5  
# Mode  :character   Median :2.0  
#                    Mean   :2.0  
#                    3rd Qu.:2.5  
#                    Max.   :3.0
```

Now turn the columns to factors.

```
cols <- sapply(df, is.character)
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], factor)
summary(df)

#  a           b      
# a:1   Min.   :1.0  
# b:1   1st Qu.:1.5  
# c:1   Median :2.0  
#       Mean   :2.0  
#       3rd Qu.:2.5  
#       Max.   :3.0
```

If you want to turn columns to be characters use :

```
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], as.character)
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Really appreciate.