# Summary and str doesnt give factors and levels information of a data frame

Tags: r

Im am new to R (version 4.0.3) programming. Whenever I use functions `str()` and `summary()` to get the info of a data frame having numerics as well as characters, it doesn't show the 'factors' and 'levels' info in output for characters. It only shows Length, Class and Mode info. How to get the factors and levels info in output as well?

Comment: You can turn the character columns to factors. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65230279/how-to-avoid-length-class-mode-in-a-r-table-that-has-characters-and-inte/65230385#65230385

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your concerned variables are still in `"character"` format. You may use `as.factor` to convert it to `"factor"` format. *Example:*

```
dat1 <- data.frame(num=1:10,
                   chr=letters[1:10])

str(dat1)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ num: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
# $ chr: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...

summary(dat1)
# num            chr           
# Min.   : 1.00   Length:10         
# 1st Qu.: 3.25   Class :character  
# Median : 5.50   Mode  :character  
# Mean   : 5.50                     
# 3rd Qu.: 7.75                     
# Max.   :10.00    

dat1$fac <- as.factor(dat1$chr)

str(dat1)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ num: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
# $ chr: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
# $ fac: Factor w/ 10 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

summary(dat1)
#      num            chr                 fac   
# Min.   : 1.00   Length:10          a      :1  
# 1st Qu.: 3.25   Class :character   b      :1  
# Median : 5.50   Mode  :character   c      :1  
# Mean   : 5.50                      d      :1  
# 3rd Qu.: 7.75                      e      :1  
# Max.   :10.00                      f      :1  
#                                    (Other):4
```

In R 4.0.x, `data.frame()` and other functions use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` as default, whereas it was `TRUE` before. Probably a colleague of yours is using an earlier version and therefore your results differ? Using `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` produces factors. However, the new variant is rather positively received.

```
dat2 <- data.frame(num=1:10,
                   chr=letters[1:10],
                   stringsAsFactors=TRUE)

str(dat2)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ num: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
# $ chr: Factor w/ 10 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

#### Edit

`read.csv` also has a `stringsAsFactors=` argument which we may set to `TRUE`. *Example:*

```
dat3 <- data.frame(num=1:10, chr=letters[1:10])

class(dat3$chr)
# [1] "character"

write.csv(dat1, "dat1.csv")  ## store a .csv

dat4 <- read.csv("dat1.csv", stringsAsFactors=TRUE)  ## read in

class(dat4$chr)
# [1] "factor"
```

Comment: Yes you are right about that the source I am learning R from must be having an older version. That should be the reason why I was facing this issue. You explained the solution very well. Thank you.

Comment: But how to assign the characters as factors while importing the data in R. e.g. data <- read.csv("some data.csv")  ?? Where do I use stringsAsFactors=TRUE here?

Comment: @some.user `read.csv` also has a `stringsAsFactors=` argument, see edit to my answer.

Comment: @some.user PS: You may look-up available function arguments in the help file, type e.g. `?read.csv` into the console.